# Quick navigation between folders in the project on Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text-2

For example, we have lots of folders in the project, and I want quickly navigate between them. How can I do that?

Maybe there exists a command in console that opens (expand) `htdocs/js/jquery` folder and scrolls it to the top of file explorer? That may give possibility to quick navigate between lots of folders in the project. Or maybe this is accomplish-able through another tool?

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text 2/3 have option "Reveal in Side Bar" in the context menu.

Also we could even add a hotkey for this action: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269407/does-sublime-text-have-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-find-the-current-document-in-file